# How to draw circle in the place of click java script

Tags: javascript, selenium, onclick, highlight

I don't know js, I write on python, but I need to draw circles on web page at the clicked location. So, for really I use selenium and I need to see where the click is. Because I don't click the dom elements, I click coordinates and sometimes Selenium click wrong, so I want to control it.
I tried some code like below, of course it doesn't work, i don't know why. So I found the [similar solution](https://github.com/codepo8/clickhighlight/blob/master/clickhighlight.js). It doesn't work for me. So I can't find the working solution for highlighting the clicks.

```js
var canv = document.createElement('canvas');
canv.id = 'canvas';

document.body.appendChild(canv);
document.getElementById('canvas').appendChild(canv);
onclick = function showCoords(event) {
  var x = event.clientX;
  var y = event.clientY;
  var radius = 5;
  var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
  var coords = 'X coords: ' + x + ', Y coords: ' + y;
  console.log(coords);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to append the canvas to the canvas

This works

```js
var canv = document.createElement('canvas');
canv.id = 'canvas';
document.body.appendChild(canv);
var ctx = canv.getContext('2d');
canv.addEventListener("click",function(event) {
  var x = event.clientX;
  var y = event.clientY;
  var radius = 5;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
  var coords = 'X coords: ' + x + ', Y coords: ' + y;
  console.log(coords);
})
```

Comment: Great thank for your answer, yes it works, there are no errors, but the circles are not drawn. Perhaps I was inaccurate, I want to see the circle at the place of click for any web page. Maybe this is the case?

Comment: I see circles in Chrome when I run the snippet

Comment: Okay, thank you, then i do something wrong)

Comment: You need to overlay the canvas on the page if you want that to happen, but if you do that, the underlaying page will not receive the clicks

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work on my PC at all. No any circles.

Comment: It gives "undefined" nothing more

Comment: I have no) Tried to add ctx.fillStyle = 'red'; Doesn't work too(

Answer (score 0):

The decision is

```
var myCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
document.body.appendChild(myCanvas);
myCanvas.id = 'canvas';
myCanvas.style.position = 'absolute';
myCanvas.style.left = "0px";
myCanvas.style.top = "0px";
myCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
myCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
myCanvas.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  var x = event.clientX;
  var y = event.clientY;
  ctx.fillStyle = "#2980b9";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
  setTimeout(function () { ctx.clearRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height) }, 300);
})
```